# xterm display is not set

Tags: xterm

When I run:

```
xterm
```

The following text is shown:

```
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
xterm: DISPLAY is not set`
```

I don't know what the problem is. Would you help to slove this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're not running `xterm` under a GUI. GUIs (The X Window system, Wayland, ...) set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to point to the active display. In a text terminal `DISPLAY` isn't set, there's no GUI, and `xterm` won't work.